# Watching Red5 server live streaming

Tags: flash, video-streaming, red5

I am very new in Red5 server. May be it is a stupid question! I can publish live streaming but my question is how i can see this live streaming from another computer. Say my laptop is working as server and i want to see the live streaming from my friends laptop in same network. How can i do this. Any help.

Lipu

Answer (score 0):

Did you input your computer ip in your friend's browser with port?
eg. your computer's ip: `192.168.1.3` and the port is 27017
so you can access from: `http://192.168.1.3:27017` 
so is it right?

Comment: This format you showed is working well but it is accessing as a administrator but I don't want to access client computer as a administrator. For more clarification I would like to Say that I am going to support VoD(Video on Demand) service who are connected to my ISP.